# JavaFX IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I am trying to format string in TextField which includes: remove all characters that are not numbers, format numbers using DecimalFormatter and limit number of character in the TextField:

```
private void IntegerInputChecker() {
    ChangeListener<String> integerChecker = new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, 
            String newValue) {
            String pureValue = newValue;
            String formatedText = newValue;
            if (pureValue.length() <= 15) {
                // Limit the characters in TextField
                if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
                    // Replace everything excepts number
                    pureValue = newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                    formatedText = pureValue;
                }
                if (pureValue.length() > 3) {
                    // Format number
                    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat( "#,###" );
                    formatedText = formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(pureValue));
                }
                else if(pureValue.length() == 3) {
                    formatedText = pureValue.replaceAll(",", "");
                }
            }
            else {
                // Limit the characters in TextField
                formatedText = formatedText.substring(0, formatedText.length() - 1);
            }
            fieldPrice.setText(formatedText);
        }
    };

    fieldPrice.textProperty().addListener(integerChecker);
}
```

Everything works fine when I type in number **but** when I try to delete them in order, JavaFX throws an exception (the program still works fine):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start must be <= the end
```

For example, If I have **123,456,789** when I delete the number to **123,456** then it throws the above exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571994/hello-i-want-to-create-a-javafx-textfield-where-the-user-can-only-input-in-the/49575480#49575480

Comment: or in other words: use a TextFormatter ...

Comment: I still can't figure it out how to do it with TextFormatter, because it can only transform the change, not the whole text in the TextField (I searched and they were all how to restrict input by using TextFormatter)

Comment: Nevermind I found a bug in my TextFormatter lol