# Textfield JavaFX with dynamic mask for monetary values

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, textfield, currency

I'm trying to create a textfield Java FX for a financial application. I would like this texfield to follow the same pattern as the numerical fields found in ATMs. For example: in ATM the initial value in the value field is "0.00". When the user types the value he wants to extract, for example, typing starts from right to left, replacing the leading zeros ... For example, I want to withdraw $ 99.90 (user type the 9 key three times and the 0 key once) and it happens that :

0.09 -> 0.99 -> 9.99 -> 99.90

Anyone have an idea how to create this mask?

I've seen several answers on similar topics but I could not adapt any of them to my project (maybe because I'm a beginner in Java and I'm still learning about the String class, textfield methods, etc.)

Thank you in advance for your attention.

P.S .: I am not yet fluent in English, so if there is any grammatical error in this message, it was because of the Google Translator I used to write

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571994/hello-i-want-to-create-a-javafx-textfield-where-the-user-can-only-input-in-the/49575480#49575480

Comment: I would think that it would be easier to make your own control that listens for key events, and you can do your own logic.

Comment: Indeed. The ideal would be to make my own control. However, I'm starting out in the Java programming world. This way it is necessary to study third-party codes to understand the Java syntax and autonomy to develop my own logic. So I look forward to an example to solve this question

Answer (score 1):

The basic algorithm is the following (pseudo code):

```cpp
float value = 0; // The initial value is 0

// On Input
void input( int digit ){ // This is invoked when the user presses a digit on the keyboard
    // You multiply the current value by ten and add the new digit
    value *= 10;
    value += digit * 0.01;
}
```

You will get the following steps for the `9990` input:

```
1: (0.00 * 10) + (9 * 0.01) = 0.09
2: (0.09 * 10) + (9 * 0.01) = 0.99
3: (0.99 * 10) + (9 * 0.01) = 9.99
4: (9.99 * 10) + (0 * 0.01) = 99.90
```